Deeper explanation of why Spin-Echo's 180 degree refocusing pulse recovers static magnetic field inhomogeneities vs Gradien-Echo which does not
I have studied the Spin-Echo pulse sequence for some time now, and read many explanations in different books and courses.
I know that the 180 degrees RF pulse (applied half way between the 90 degrees excitation RF pulse), causes the spins in a sample to come back into phase at TE and "kiss" the T2 relaxation curve, so to speak, and recover any static magnetic field inhomogeneities.
The Gradient echo (GRE) is performed with a negative lobe of a gradient field, compensated by a positive one, creating a GRE at TE, which meets the T2* curve and does not recover magnetic field inhomogeneities.
I've included a photo montage of the best explanation I have found in a book called "from picture to proton", which also provides the "extended runners on a track analogy", with varying lane conditions representing the inhomogeneities.
I can visually see, on the SE diagram, that the black and blue spin arrows are "swapped" for the SE, where as they are not for the GRE. But physically, it is not really clear how exactly these inhomogeneities are "recovered" by the $180^{\circ}$ pulse.
It would seem that, the spins change locations and experience different inhomog., but some details are missing...
I would be very grateful if someone has a very detailed understanding of this and would share it here.


why did i get a -1?

The -1 is weird to me also.

ok someone had the good idea to remove the -1 ! I mean if this is not accepted as a question i don't know what would be...

What is TE and SE?

TE= Time to Echo and SE = Spin Echo

The book "from picture to proton" seems really interesting to understand better MRI... I have never found such clear images. Thanks!

I don't know if you managed to solve outside from here... I think yes since the question has been asked 4 months ago. Since I have the same doubt, I posted the same question with my thinking here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/838545/why-does-the-spin-echo-sequence-refocus-dephase-due-to-magnetic-field-inhomogene. Maybe it can be useful either for you or for me.

The important quantity to pay attention to is the phase. The phase is just the direction that a given spin is pointing in the transverse plane. An echo consists of all the spins having the same phase, meaning they are all pointing in the same direction. This is called phase coherence.
So let’s see the conditions in which a collection of spins can lose phase coherence and then regain it. First, let’s assume that the main magnetic field is completely uniform and everything is ideal. In that case, the phase of the spin is due entirely to the gradients and the position $$\phi(t,\vec r)=\vec r \cdot \vec k(t)$$ where $$\vec k(t)=\int_{t_0}^{t}\gamma \ \vec G(t) \ dt +\vec k(t_0)$$ is the k-space. Note that when $\vec k=0$ we have $\phi=0$, regardless of $\vec r$. This is an echo, and as it is produced by manipulating the gradients, it is called a gradient echo.
Now, instead of assuming that everything is uniform and ideal, let’s assume that there is some spatial in homogeneity in the magnetic field $\Delta B_0(\vec r)$ so the phase is given by $$\phi(t,\vec r)= (t-t_0) \gamma \ \Delta B_0(\vec r)+\phi(t_0,\vec r)$$
Now, immediately after an ideal excitation pulse we have $\phi(t_{excite^+},\vec r)=0$ where $t_{excite^+}$ is the time immediately after the excitation pulse. After an ideal refocusing pulse we have $\phi(t_{refocus^+},\vec r)=-\phi(t_{refocus^-}, \vec r)$ where $t_{refocus^-}$ is the time immediately before the refocusing pulse, and so forth.
Combining these we can calculate $\phi(t,\vec r)$ assuming an excitation pulse at $t=0$ and a refocusing pulse at $t=\tau$ we then find that $\phi(2\tau,\vec r)=0$. This is a spin echo.
More intuitively, the $\Delta B(\vec r)$ means that spins in different locations precess at different rates, gaining phase at different rates.
Those spins that gain phase at a higher rate get “ahead”. Then, the refocusing pulse reverses the phase so that the spins that were the most “ahead” become the furthest “behind”. But although they are the furthest behind, they still fain phase at the highest rate, so they catch up. The spin echo is the moment when they all return to their initial phase.

thanks for the effort, but this is not exactly the explanation i am looking for. I know what the phase is and understand the concept that spins start in phase just after the 90 then loose phase because the experience differences in magn. field whether by a gradient or static inhom. but my q. is more about intuitive (and if you want mathematical) explanations of why the spin-echo is able to refocus the static inhomog. with its 180 and the GRE echo is not, maybe you see what i mea? ( i noticed a missing gamma in front of your integral so that the dim. of $\vec{k}$ ends up in $\textrm{m}^{-1}$)

@AlanTuring oops, yes, I corrected it. That said, then I don’t understand your question. What you wrote seems like what I answered. The 180 reverses the phase while the gradients don’t. It is that reversal that is what matters, as I described

haha strange ... but then can you compare with the GRE ? (compare SE vs GRE ) to show why in the case of the SE with the 180 pulse the inhomog. are corrected and not when refocusing with the inverted gradient polarity. I mean i kinda "learned" by heart that SE refocuses inhomog. but how do you explain that these inhomog. are not corrected by GRE ( i mean other than just saying that it doesnt use the 180 which i know, but physically maybe if you can describe what happens with the phase maybe ?

perhaps the key is to compare them, i mean SE and GRE? Also not exactly sure what you mean by the terminology with the t_refocus+ and - ? i guess t_refocus means "the instant in time when the spins come bk into phase after the 180" i.e. TE? but why + and -?

The + and - refer to times immediately after and before. $t_{refocus}$ refers to the time of the refocusing (180 deg) RF pulse, not TE. I have clarified in the text

ok, then if i understand correctly now, the formula means that just after the 180, the phase of each spin is negated, so this is the mathematical description of the sentence "the spins that were leading are now lagging, and vice versa" yes ?

@AlanTuring yes

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
