Why does the Spin Echo sequence refocus dephase due to magnetic field inhomogeneities and gradient echo does not?
My explanations come from Richard Buxton's book (Introduction to functional magnetic resonance imaging).
We know that Spin Echo sequence can be summerized as

90° pulse - wait TE/2 - 180° pulse - wait TE/2 - measure

The 180° pulse is able to refocus dephasing due to magnetic field inhomogeneities. I can understand this thanks to the movies of spins that are flipped with the 180°, achieve coherence and, as a consequence, produce an echo.  I can understand it even better considering this extract from the above cited book:

Note that although a 180° pulse will correct for field
inhomogeneities, it will not refocus true T2 decay. The reason an echo
forms is that the phase acquired during the interval before the 180°
pulse is exactly the same as the phase acquired during the interval
after the pulse. But the phase variations associated with T2 decay are
caused by fluctuating fields, and the pattern of fluctuations is not
repeated before and after the RF pulse. In short, an SE reverses the
dephasing effects of static fields but not fluctuating fields.

Hence, Spin Echo produces an echo thanks to the 180° pulse. The peak of this echo touches the T2 relaxation curve.
Gradient echo, instead, produces an echo thanks to the application of a negative gradient followed by a positive one. The first one gives to the spin a phase, the second one refocus the spins which achieve coherence and this produces an echo.
Now the question is: the peak of the gradient echo touches the T2* relaxation curve because the refocusing has not refocused the dephasing due to inhomogeneities but refocuses the phase acquired with the negative gradient which is different from the phase due to magnetic field inhomogeneities ?
I know that the same question has been already asked here: Deeper explanation of why Spin-Echo's 180 degree refocusing pulse recovers static magnetic field inhomogeneities vs Gradien-Echo which does not. However, it has not been answered yet.
